# Correlation: Concept to Formula

Tags: correlation

In digital signal processing, we calculate the correlation between two discrete signals by multiplying corresponding samples of the two signals and then adding the products.  Where does this process/formula for correlation come from?

I understand the concept of correlation (similarity) between two signals.  But I fail to understand how it translates to the formula that it does.

All the texts I have seen so far start with this formula and explain cross correlation, auto correlation, etc.  None of them attempt to explain how the formula was derived in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The euclidean distance between two signals $(a_i)_i$ and $(b_i)_i$ that have euclidean magnitude equal to 1 is $\sum_i (a_i - b_i)^2 = \sum_i a_i^2 + \sum_i b_i^2 - 2 \sum_i a_i b_i = 2- 2 \sum_i a_i b_i$. So the correlation naturally arises as equivalent to the negative of the distance. If you believe that euclidean distance measures closeness, then closeness is high (distance is low) when the correlation (sum of products) is high, and vice versa. I hope that makes it more intuitive.

Comment: I kind of get it, but have to think more on this.  Why consider the special case of magnitude equal to 1?  I realize that the final result in your answer also tells that $\sum_i a_i b_i $ = 1 produces maximum correlation and zero distance.

Comment: @iaswtw The reason I chose magnitude equal to one is that this gives you exactly the sum-of-products as the quantity of interest for the distance, and also correlation normalizes the two vectors so they have magnitude equal to 1 anyway. If the points have different magnitudes then the sum-of-products is also important but you also get the squared magnitudes appearing in the squared distance. If you hold the magnitudes fixed then the distance is again equivalent to the sum of products.